# Cannot access Websphere

Tags: java, linux, websphere, maximo

I'm trying to deploy a Maximo server but cannot get in Websphere to do anything. The environment is Linux and I'm not very experienced with it, I have only worked on Windows so far.

When I try to start up WebSphere by using this command:

```
WAS_HOME\profiles\IICEServer\bin\startServer.bat webserver1
```

It returns this:

```
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
       /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/webserver1/startServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: webserver1
ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
httpd (pid 26132) already running
ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. startServer.log,
       SystemOut.log(or job log in zOS) and other log files under
       /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/webserver1
       should contain failure information.
```

I checked all the log files that I can think of (there is no systemOut.log file in the logs folder, usually there should be one but I don't know why it is not there) and found only in the startServer.log mentioning this:

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
Host Operating System is Linux, version 2.6.18-308.el5
Java version = JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux amd64-64 jvmxa6460sr12-20121024_126067 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20121024_126067
JIT  - r9_20120914_26057
GC   - 20120928_AA, Java Compiler = j9jit24, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
user.install.root = /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01
Java Home = /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre
ws.ext.dirs = /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/web/help:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/properties:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/startup.jar:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/amd64/default:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/amd64:/maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin::/usr/lib
Current trace specification = *=info
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[11/5/14 16:18:17:964 MYT] 00000000 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info.
[11/5/14 16:18:18:031 MYT] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
[11/5/14 16:18:18:033 MYT] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: webserver1
[11/5/14 16:18:18:176 MYT] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
[11/5/14 16:18:18:201 MYT] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. startServer.log, SystemOut.log(or job log in zOS) and other log files under /maximo/software/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/webserver1 should contain failure information.
```

Which also does not help.

If I try to get into WebSphere using the browser:

```
https://localhost:9043/ibm/console
```

then it will display this error message:

```
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console has not been defined.


SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle localhost:9043 has not been defined.
```

Would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to start `server1` not `webserver1`, like this:

```
WAS_HOME\profiles\IICEServer\bin\startServer.bat server1
```

to be sure about the server name run the status command:

```
WAS_HOME\profiles\IICEServer\bin\serverStatus.bat -all
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be webserver1, if I run serverStatus:

ADMU0508I: The Node Agent "nodeagent" is STARTED
ADMU0509I: The Application Server "MXPROD_MIF_01_01" cannot be reached. It
           appears to be stopped.
ADMU0509I: The Application Server "MXPROD_BIRT_01_01" cannot be reached. It
           appears to be stopped.
ADMU0508I: The Web server "webserver1" is RUNNING
ADMU0509I: The Application Server "MXPROD_CRON_01_01" cannot be reached. It
           appears to be stopped.

Funny it is saying webserver1 is RUNNING

Comment: @Kenny If you have NodeAgent, then somewhere should be deployment manager and you administer via that server. So go to your `WAS_HOME\profiles` and check what other profiles do you have. There should be other profile with deployment manager. Check serverStatus in other profiles also.